# Iterate through broken JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I am currently attempting to write a script to iterate through a JSON object (which unfortunately I cannot change the structure of).

However I belive the JSON is not valid as there is no Key.

### This is the Structure of my JSON:

```
{
    "0": {
        "name": "You",
        "message": "dwd"
    },
    "1": {
        "name": "You",
        "message": "asa"
    },
    "2": {
        "name": "You",
        "message": "this is the message that the user is faced with boi"
    },
    "3": {
        "name": "You",
        "message": "asas"
    },
    "4": {
        "name": "You",
        "message": "asasasas"
    },
    "5": {
        "name": "You",
        "message": "asas"
    },
    "6": {
        "name": "You",
        "message": "sdsd"
    },
    "7": {
        "name": "You",
        "message": "asdfg"
    },
    "8": {
        "name": "You",
        "message": "asas"
    },
    "9": {
        "name": "You",
        "message": "asas"
    }
}
```

This is the current script that I have, however this does not seem to iterate through this object.

```
for (var key in greetings){
            name  = greetings[key].name
            console.log(name)
            msg = greetings[key].message
            tag = '<ul>'+name+' wrote: '+message+'</ul>'
            ul = ul + tag
        }
```

Any help would be great

EDIT:

Here is some more information. The greetings object is sent from a server and is fetched via a XMLHTTPRequest, as seen below

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                greetings = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
                console.log(greetings);
            }
        };
```

As for the loop, the varaible reassignment is so that the HTML (I want to make each object in this list its own tag)

Comment: That string is valid JSON. Try http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: perhaps you're looking for [Object.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), to add in your loop (so you don't iterate over prototype properties)

Comment: Ahh in that Case it must be my loop that isnt working, any ideas for that?

Comment: The `for` loop isn't enough to tell us what's going wrong here. That for loop will iterate through a "greetings" object just fine, and do some variable assignment. I'm noticing a couple problems - you don't actually seem to be *doing* anything with those variables (which were perhaps declared elsewhere?) and we can't see how you're parsing that JSON object.

Comment: What kind of errors are you seeing? What are you not seeing that you would expect to? How are you "grabbing" that `greetings` object?

Comment: Ok, so the greetings object is sent back from a server as JSON and then Parsed as a json object

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       greetings = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
          console.log(greetings);
      }
  };

Comment: I will edit the main post so code is clear

Comment: The loop is fine and the JSON is fine. I think the problem might be that you tried to reference the undefined variable `message` instead of `msg`.

Comment: When are you running the for loop? Is it after you receive data from the server (remembering that XMLHttpRequests are asynchronous)?

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(key)` inside the `for` loop? you say there is not key.. prove it :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Patrick Bar, it seems that this code was executing before the async callback from the server request. This has now been fixed. Many thanks for all of the comments